# How to use sprites within a web page

Tags: css, sprite

I have been intrigued about using sprite images.

For educational reasons I have been studying the CSS of SO and found out that instead of seperate images, items for like the up + down vote amongst other things is taken from an entire png image.

```
background-image:url('img/sprites.png?v=5')
```

How would I go about pulling an individual image from an assembled png? so I can put it on use within my site, this it seems more efficient than having tons of images in a sub directory, rather than a collection of the main images within 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is `background-position`: You build such a sprites image and then calculate the offset for each image. Then you set the appropriate value. You also have so specify the correct width and height for the element holding your background.

Example (from the up arrow here):

```
background-position: 0 -265px;
height: 25px;
width: 41px;
```

You set the same `background-image` but different positions.

Comment: So I would need to gather the co-ords of the position of the sprite within the actual document, how would I go about that one?

Comment: For example use photoshop (or gimp) and display a ruler. Additionally maybe you could set those grid lines to make looking the coordinates up easier. Another way is trial and error: Use Firebug (or equivalent) and modify your CSS until it fits.

Comment: You decide the position of each sprite in your image, and you just put those co-ordinates and the size into CSS.  There's nothing magic about it, but if you want to you could write a program to create the image and CSS using a bunch of files as input.

Comment: Note that the CSS x/y is negative to the x/y position of each sprite because you're moving the image up and left not down and right.